# Placed as a grad with client who now want to recruit me, but I'm planning to move to a location where they have another office. How to proceed?

Tags: career-development, united-kingdom, careers

I work in the tech industry in uk. I am part of what is called a graduate scheme and got placed in a company for a certain amount of time. A graduate scheme basically trains you, then places you in one of their client's company for the amount of a contract you signed (sometimes you can be switched between multiple clients).

My problem is the following: My client really likes me and want to buy me to my company earlier than the initial contract (it is possible). Great! This means they have a perm (not a consultant anymore) and I have a better salary.
However, I know I will move to another city soon and will then want to change offices (they have an office in the city I will be going to).

The train is quite expensive (thousands per year) between these 2 cities, plus it would take between 1h and 1h30 to come to the office (therefore, around 2h30 of travel for the day). I know I will not wish to continue to work at my initial office/team very long (work-life balance, costs, ...).  Some people of the office do.

I do like and respect my team. My managers feel the same towards me. I do a great job and I know they might want to keep me in the company. But moving office might be a problem for them.

My question is: do I come clean with the fact I will move AND that I will ask to move office as well? I could come sometimes to the initial one, but I don't want 1) to do it too much, 2) to pay the trains as it is very expensive. I am afraid to do so because this could cause them to rethink hiring me earlier.

I am a person that tries to always be open and honest - therefore I feel a bit conflicted. I respect my manager, but I am afraid of what could happen if I came clean.

Thanks.

Edit: I intended initially to wait after the moment my contract "expired" with my initial employer to mention this move. There is an amount of time I have to work for the client, even if they recruit me as a perm (it seems a bit complex if you are not familiar with the system). I thought this would allow both parties to 1)get my perm position, 2) be sure for the company that I now am part of the company and not a contractor of some sort.  This means that I don't "lie" as I do intend to stay working for them, but I know at some point my situation will change, and I am aware of it.

Edit2: I did mention I was gonna move at some point. They said we could find an arrengement but I would still work for the team of City1, having to come at least half the week to office1. It was never mentioned (well, I didn't mention it neither) to work for the other office of City2, which makes me think this might be a problem.

Comment: I proposed an edit to the question title to make it a little bit more explicit to what you are asking, as I hope that would attract more answers (as I think it's a really good Q!) It's awaiting peer review but once it's reviewed, feel free to roll it back if it doesn't suit. :)

Answer (score 5):

Just be honest with yourself and company and this shall come to good. In fact, you shall discuss with your company the reasons behind your decision to move to another city and they would try some middle way if possible.

After taking training or buyout of the contract, it will be a difficult situation for both parties to break up.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is assuming you will definitely be moving to *City 2* regardless of what happens with your employer, the client, etc.**

If it would be a practical and appropriate option for you to work for the client at their 'City 2' location (e.g. their office in City 2 would be a suitable place to carry out whatever your job function is)...

Given the circumstances you outlined here I would suggest you should be honest and open with your employer -- and have that conversation sooner rather than later. The discussion would be something like: you already have concrete plans to move to City 2 in "whatever time frame it is", you know that the client has offices there, you are seeking to work for the client from that office. *How can we make that happen?*

It doesn't sound like it would be feasible or sustainable for you to continue to travel between your current area (client location) and City 2 once you have moved. In which case you would then be faced with having to have that conversation later about whether they could transfer you to another office (when you are relatively new) or if that's not possible for some reason... have to quit and look for something else.

I'm sure they wouldn't want you to quit and look for something else, given that they are presumably happy with your work, you are contributing positively to their company and have made a very good impression even in the short-ish (I'm inferring, I realise you didn't state how long you have been working with that client but I infer it is about 6 months max) period you've been there.

Currently you are in a position of strength -- they like you, so much so that they are wanting to buy you out early from your graduate scheme (which may involve its own costs, fees etc). Use this to your advantage.

*Edited to add: and if it is a problem for the client that you would want to move offices -- better to know this sooner rather than later. If it is really a no-go you will then have a head start on lining up other opportunities in City 2. I think your chances are better, if anything, of getting them to agree this change of location now rather than when you've worked for them directly for only a short time.*